# StreamWriter fails with large amount of data

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, streamwriter

I'm using StreamWriter to pass a large amount of data (30mb+) via a WebRequest POST. It fails with the error **The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.** Contrary to the error message, I am not performing concurrent operations -- the app is single threaded and the StreamWriter logic is very straightforward.

```
string data = "......."; // 30mb+ of text

var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(someUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    writer.Write(data);
```

I suspect the large amount of data is to blame. I've seen references to this error from Team Foundation System users who get this error when uploading large files ([[1]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/a68c0c64-78c2-41d0-80fa-6dac5a696d2a/), [[2]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/b088a2c1-ebc0-438d-a574-72a1afacc23c/)), however I haven't seen large data being discussed as the cause outside of TFS discussions.

Am I truly running into some limit with StreamWriter? Is there are more efficient way to stream this data?

Comment: can you try to send the data directly to the streamwriter without cahcing on a single string?

Comment: Can you try this test code? `string data = "Ç"; 
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            Console.WriteLine(data.Length);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(m))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
                writer.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(m.Length);
            }`

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the length of the *encoded* text is the same as the number of *characters* in the text. How confident are you in that assumption? (Is all the text ASCII?)

Comment: @FelipeOriani No, the data originates from another source and I receive it as a string.

Comment: @JonSkeet & I4V -- good point about the text length. The text *should* be ASCII but I will have to double check. If it isn't, could that be the source of the stated problem or would it be a separate issue?

Comment: My text is all ASCII. But I found out that the "concurrent IO" error is masking the true error which is the server rejecting my large POST payload. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem was my POST request was so large that I had exceeded the target server's [maxAllowedContentLength](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) setting. The fix was to increase the value of this setting.

I'm not sure why I got a "concurrent IO" error but it only happened when I set `webRequest.ContentLength`. When I commented that line out I was able to see the WebRequest received a 404 from the server. This eventually led me to discover the issue with maxAllowedContentLength.